# Flutter - Non-nullable instance field after change SDK version

Tags: flutter, dart

After change SDK from sdk: **">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"** to sdk: **">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"**

Get error:

[image]

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future <List<Data>> futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData();
  }
```

What is your SDK version?  I'm change version because I'm get suggestion for some widget where is min sdk 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Flutter 2, it is Null-Safety. You example is not,

Official reference:
https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety

Ways to make this work

```
  //Key is optional
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  //Key is mandatory and must be set
  MyApp({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  //futureData may be null
  Future <List<Data>>? futureData;

  //You ensure that futureData contains data before being accessed
  late Future <List<Data>> futureData;
```